# QIcon.Selected attribute apparently not available in PyQt6

Tags: python, pyqt6

I have a python program that I wrote about a year and a half ago that used PyQt5 on a Mac. I'm currently trying to run it on Windows 11. Because of various issues I decided to move to PySide6 and PyQt6. This got rid of several issues, but just kicked the can further down the street.

I have this bit of code:

`icon = QIcon() icon.addPixmap(QPixmap("Resources/AmenicIcon.png"), QIcon.Selected, QIcon.On)`
I had imported the Qt stuff like this:

`from PyQt6.QtWidgets import * from PyQt6.QtCore import * from PyQt6.QtGui import QPixmap, QPainter, QPen, QPalette, QIcon, QColor, QStandardItemModel, QStandardItem, QGuiApplication`

When compiled I see this error:

```
  File "C:\Users\jshol\Documents\python stuff\AMENIC\amenic.py", line 2784, in __init__
    icon.addPixmap(QPixmap("Resources/AmenicIcon.png"), QIcon.Selected, QIcon.On)
                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: type object 'QIcon' has no attribute 'Selected'
```

I'd previously seen some attributes that had been 'reorganised' in PyQt6 (for example Qt.DisplayRole has magically become Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole), but no such change seems to be claimed for QIcon. The documentation [here](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/PySide6/QtGui/QIcon.html) implies there is still a 'Selected' attribute.

Does anyone know how to access QIcon.selected in PyQt6?

Comment: The definiton of QIcon in  QtGui.pyi in both PyQt6 and PySide6 contain a Selected attribute, so I'm guessing that the definition of QIcon is coming from somewhere else

Comment: Since PyQt6 started using python enums you have to include the full enum name (similar to the mentioned ItemDataRole). In this case you have to use `QIcon.Mode.Selected`

Comment: And `QIcon.On` should be changed to `QIcon.State.On`

Comment: Thanks. Kind of obvious when you know. I realise I wasn't looking at the class definition carefully enough. Do you know if these changes are listed in any unified way anywhere, or is it just a question of looking at the class definiton more carefully when you find an enum 'missing'.

Comment: @JohnH *All* flags and enums have been changed. So, whenever you use any, you have to assume that the full namespace is required. If you can't remember it, just go to the C++ documentation of the class: they are normally listed in the "Public Types" section (see the case for [QIcon](//doc.qt.io/qt-6/qicon.html#public-types)) or eventually just use the search function in your browser. Don't use the PyQt docs (they are almost unmaintained), nor the PySide/Qt for Python pages (they are often misleading and sometimes inconsistent since they're automatically built).

Comment: @musicamante That's pretty much the conclusion I'd come to. I've just been poking around in the .pyi files to find the correct definitions. Another effect of putting the enums in a class is that they are now type checked, so whereas previously, if you knew an enum's numeric value, you could save yourself some typing, you now *have* to use the symbolic name or it just fails the type check. Which I suppose some would say is a good thing.

Comment: @JohnH Yes, the major drawback of the new syntax is that enums have become a bit cumbersome due to the length of the full names: Qt is notably verbose in its naming, which is normally a good thing, except when you have to write and read `SomethingWithVeryLongName.AndAnotherLongEnum.Value`. In any case, there's no point in checking the pyi, just look at the docs, which are always consistent (and more informative). Note that the main reason behind this change wasn't about typing, but proper behavior: consistency, correct management of binary operators, and even accurate representation in debug.